# How to style WebView default Loader in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, react-redux, react-native-webview

```
<WebView
 source={{ uri: this.state.url }}
 startInLoadingState={<ActivityIndicator
 style={{backgroundColor: Color.transparent, position: 'absolute', left: width * 0.35, top: height / 2 - 50, zIndex: 9,height: width * 0.3,width: width * 0.3,borderRadius: 20}}
 color={Color.white}
 size="large" />}
/>
```

**Below is my code**

I want actives indicator  in WebView default property

```
startInLoadingState={}
```

here I add but it's not working so what I can do

to add styel in defalut startInLoadingState={}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startInLoadingState` is boolean, not is a JSX.Element.

If you want to custom your loading, just use `renderLoading` prop and you need turn on `startInLoadingState` to use `renderLoading` prop.

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: "https://source.com" }}
  startInLoadingState // or `startInLoadingState={true}`
  renderLoading={() => <ActivityIndicator
    style={{
        backgroundColor: Color.transparent, position: 'absolute', left: width * 0.35, top: height / 2 - 50, zIndex: 9,
        height: width * 0.3,
        width: width * 0.3,
        borderRadius: 20
    }}
    color={Color.white}
    size="large" />}
/>
```

Reference: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#renderloading

Comment: It's not working it's give me error Like this......can't find loading

Comment: @DharaPatel replace `<Loading />` by your Loading component. hm, i modified my example.